# How can you use a Spring DataSourceInitializer with both a @Primary and secondary DataSource bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a scenario where I'd like to have a `@Primary DataSource` bean that depends on another `DataSource` bean. I am currently encountering a `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` exception when I do this because the `DataSourceInitializer` triggers resolution of the `@Primary` bean while it is still being created.

I've created an example repository that reproduces this issue and explains it in more detail, if helpful: https://github.com/zachmarshall/spring-datasource-init-bug

Comment: Have you tried naming the bean of `primaryDataSource` in `ExampleConfig` class like `@Bean(name="primDataSource")` other than the bean instantiated by Spring container?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @harshavmb. Unfortunately, changing the bean name has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9394) was created for this. There was acknowledgement that the code is at least problematic, but no real resolution yet.

Ultimately, I did find a [workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9394#issuecomment-308726644):

> ...by using `@DependsOn("dataSourceInitializer")` on the `@Primary` bean definition, spring eagerly creates the `dataSourceInitializer` bean before the primary is marked as in creation. Kind of a hack but works for now.

Comment: any solution to the problem in SpringBoot 2?